# Summary statistics of column values based on another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having a table storing user's trips, trips' segments and the corresponding type of travel mode used to cover the trip, like so:

```sql
CREATE TABLE segments(trip_id INT, segment_id INT, type VARCHAR(25));

INSERT INTO segments(trip_id, segment_id, type)
VALUES (533521,1,'car'),(533521,3,'car'),(533521,7,'car'),(533521,9,'car'),
    (533526,0,'walk'),(533526,10,'walk'),(533526,16,'walk'),(533526,20,'walk'),
    (533528,1,'car'),(533528,3,'car'),(533528,5,'car'),(533528,9,'car'),
    (533531,0,'walk'),(533532,1,'car'),(533536,0,'subway'),(533536,0,'subway'),
    (533536,2,'subway'),(533536,2,'subway'),(533537,6,'bus'),(533537,9,'bus');
```

So that:

```sql
SELECT * FROM segments LIMIT 5;
trip_id segment_id type
533521     1       car
533521     3       car
533521     7       car
533521     9       car
533526     0       walk
```

Trips have uneven number of segments, and `segment_id` isn't sequential (short segments and non-moving segments removed). For example, trip `533528` have 4 segments `1,3,5,9`.

Some travel type have more segments than others. For example, although `car` travel longer than `walk`, the `walk` type have more segments than `car` in most cases due to frequent stops.

How do I produce statistics of:

- `type` with highest number `segments` per `trip`.
- average number of `segments` per `trip` per `type`.

I am required to give a summary statistics of segments produced per trip per type.

**Note:**  [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kQ-7PqNB).

Answer (score 0):

Here are your queries

```sql
-- type with highest number segments per trip. pick the top rows only
select type, trip_id, count(segment_id) segments_count
from segments
group by type, trip_id
order by segments_count desc;

-- average number of segments per trip per type
select avg(segments_count) segments_average
from 
(
 select count(segment_id) segments_count
 from segments
 group by type, trip_id
) t;
```